# Android Facebook login without Facebook login button

Tags: android, android-facebook

I want login with facebook without using Facebook Login Button. so i applied click event on default android button.

But i got error `cannot resolve method logInWithReadPermissions(..)..`

here is my code. Any help will appreciated

```
btnFBLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v)
       {    
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));// here giving error can not resolve method
       }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are currently passing reference of button

But you need to pass reference of Activity

Please use the below code that might help you.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the

```
LoginActivity.this // name of the activity and `.this`
```

instead of `this` in Button `onClick()` function. If you using `this` in this case it means you referring to the `Button` not the Activity.
**Because** this refers to the subsequent parent which is in this case Button.
If you use the same code in `onCreate()` method (not in any click listener etc.) that's fine Because in that case `this` refers to the activity.