# Android Facebook login issues

Tags: android

I want login with facebook without using Facebook Login Button. so i applied click event on default android button.

But i got error cannot resolve method logInWithReadPermissions(..)..

here is my code. Any help will appreciated

```
btnFBLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v)
       {    
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));// here giving error can not resolve method
       }
});
```

Comment: Check Here:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605127/android-facebook-login-without-facebook-login-button/32606180#32606180

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently passing reference of button

But you need to pass reference of Activity

Please use the below code that might help you.

See here

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
```

Comment: the name and pic is same for both op and the 'Answerer'!!

Comment: Don't worry guys